# How to implement OData Core with async await?

Tags: odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm implementing OData for a personal project. At this moment I have this code

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ODataRoute("Classes", RouteName = "PostClass")]
    public IActionResult PostClass([FromBody] Class @class)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        @class.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        _context.Classes.Add(@class);
        _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        //return CreatedAtAction("GetClass", new { id = @class.Id }, @class);
        return Created(@class);
    }
```

It is working fine but I would like if I can improve it with sync await system like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ODataRoute("Classes", RouteName = "PostClass")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Class>> PostClass([FromBody] Class @class)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        @class.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        _context.Classes.Add(@class);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetClass", new { id = @class.Id }, @class);
        //return Created(@class);
    }
```

When I do this second solution the code build but I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

With

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ODataRoute("Classes", RouteName = "PostClass")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Class>> PostClass([FromBody] Class @class)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        @class.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        _context.Classes.Add(@class);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        //return CreatedAtAction("GetClass", new { id = @class.Id }, @class);
        return Created(@class);
    }
```

The code cannot build because

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Results.CreatedODataResult'
>   to
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult'   Oyg.Api C:\Users\Public\Projects\oyg-server\Api\Controllers\ClassesController.cs    96  Active

Ok clear but then what method should I use in place of Created() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the type [CreatedODataResult](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/7db042340db1aefd623c07f7d18b1985449b7625/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/Results/CreatedODataResult.cs#L21) returned by the [`Created<TEntity>(entity)` method](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/d02bc61ea7b31ada1e54abbeebbecb3c5df0e3ac/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/ODataController.cs#L27) is not a subclass of ActionResult, but a class that [implements the `IActionResult` interface](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/7db042340db1aefd623c07f7d18b1985449b7625/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/Results/CreatedODataResult.cs#L21):

```
public class CreatedODataResult<T> : IActionResult
{
    // ...
}
```

To fix your code, simply change the `Task<ActionResult<Class>>` to be `Task<IActionResult>` :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ODataRoute("Classes", RouteName = "PostClass")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostClass([FromBody] Class @class)
    {
        // ...
        return Created(@class);
    }
```